# Можно ли интегрировать Node.js в Django?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, django

Я только начал программировать и ради интереса решил написать небольшой сайт на Django. Теперь, когда сайт готов, я хотел бы добавить туда анимации, но не знаю как. Мне говорили, что многие пользуются Node.js для анимации своих сайтов. Node.js и Django два разных фреймворка, поэтому возник вопрос "Можно ли интегрировать Node.js в мой сайт написанный на Django?"

Comment: В такой интеграции нет никакого смысла. Django работает на бэкенде, js-код с анимацией сайта — на фронтенде (в браузере). Если вам нужно запустить анимацию js-кодом — просто поместите нужный вам js-код на нужную вам страницу любым удобным вам способом, а Django здесь вообще совершенно ни при чём. Возможно, понадобится прописать ссылку на js-файл в каком-нибудь Django-шаблоне — больше никакой интеграции и не надо.

Comment: Любая анимация это на клиенте в браузере. Django и Node.js это серверная часть которая отвечает на запрос браузера страничкой либо другими данными. Так Вот анимация это либо стиль либо JS который может спокойно отправить  Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все манипуляции с элементами сайта по мимо css можно производить с помощью JavaScript который уже встроен в браузер (node не нужен).
Использовать JavaScript на странице можно в тегах `<script></script>`
Или подключив по ссылке `<script src="/path/to/script.js"></script>`.

Более подробное описание найдёшь на этом ресурсе
https://learn.javascript.ru/external-script